# how to tell date?

Tags: english-to-japanese, time

when someone ask, what is the date for a program? and the answer is 5th may. how can i answer this in japanese. i know that 5th is いつか　and may is ごがつ。which one should be pronounced first. and how do i say the years? 2017 for example? i am a beginner in japanese. hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

２０１７年５月５日

にせんじゅうななねん　ごがつ　いつか

In Japanese it goes Year >> Month >> Date.

Comment: ありがとうございました。。your answer helped me